# Use git non invasively

Tags: git

I have a somewhat nasty build system that will choke as soon as it finds any unexpected files or directories. I'd like to add version control with git now without any change in the build process. (I can not/do not want to change this at the moment.)

Problem: Git will also leave some files/directories in that tree.

**Is there a way to have git store any of its file externally and not put anything into the version controlled directories?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes set the environment variable GIT_DIR to another directory, then use GIT as normal.  Git will use the directory specified by GIT_DIR for all it's repository files.

Comment: It's that easy? Cool! :-)

Comment: as long as you can remember 1)that GIT_DIR needs to be set and 2)what it should be next time you come back to it.  see also core.worktree in `git help config`